# How to filter/drop row based on subquery condition within Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working in pandas and want to drop few rows based on a sub condition.

Dataset

| System | Category |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 2 |
| E | 2 |
| F | 2 |
| G | 1 |

I want to drop system rows having category value as 2 provided it(like A and D) has both category 1 and 2. If only category 2 alone is present for the system(like E and F), then no need to drop it.

Require output as below

| System | Category |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| E | 2 |
| F | 2 |
| G | 1 |

I tried pd.drop which has option to drop based on directly removing all system having category 2 but no option to provide a sub condition as explained above. Please suggest

Comment: If you can provide a dataset such that we can copy, it would be easier for us!!

Comment: Since the dataset is simple, I created it this time. Please make sure to post dataset next time!

Answer (score 1):

You can first sort the column(first by system then by category).
Then remove the duplicate from System.

```
df.sort_values(['System', 'Category'], ascending=[True, True], inplace = True)
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['System'], keep = 'first', inplace = True)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would want to remove rows with the conditions

- Length of `System` group is > 1 and
- `Category` is 2

```py
m = (df.groupby('System')['Category'].transform(len) > 1) & (df['Category'] == 2)
df = df[~m].reset_index(drop=True)
```

print(df):

```
  System  Category
0      A         1
1      B         1
2      C         1
3      D         1
4      E         2
5      F         2
6      G         1
```